# How to override a matplotlib property when using plt.style.use()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use seaborn-dark style in matplotlib, but override the spines being invisible.

Example A - using the style before setting the spines visible means I get seaborn-dark style but I do not get green spines.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")

figure = plt.figure(1, figsize=(11, 11))
ax = plt.gca()

assert(isinstance(ax, plt.Axes))
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set()
    spine.set_visible(True)
    spine.set_edgecolor('g')
    spine.set_alpha(1)
plt.show()
```

Example B - using the style after setting the spines visible means you get no effects of the seaborn-dark style, but I do get green spines.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


figure = plt.figure(1, figsize=(11, 11))
ax = plt.gca()

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")

assert(isinstance(ax, plt.Axes))
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set()
    spine.set_visible(True)
    spine.set_edgecolor('g')
    spine.set_alpha(1)
plt.show()
```

I want to use the seaborn-dark style in matplotlib, but then override the spines to make them visible and green, while keeping the other features of seaborn-dark (e.g. the dark grey facecolor) the same. However, I get either one or the other, depending on whether the plt.Axes() object is instantiated before or after the call to plt.style.use().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seaborn-dark style sets the linewidth of the axes to 0. So you need to reset the linewidth property back to 1 or whatever you need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")

figure = plt.figure(1, figsize=(11, 11))
ax = plt.gca()

for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('g')
    spine.set_linewidth(1)

plt.show()
```

Since essentially you want to redefine the style, I would however recommend to change those parameters at the same level, namely the rcParams.
The below results in the same, but makes it more apparent where the parameters come from.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("seaborn-dark")
plt.rcParams.update({"axes.linewidth" : 1,
                     "axes.edgecolor" : "g"})

figure = plt.figure(1, figsize=(11, 11))
ax = plt.gca()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you - I used the first solution in the end, and it worked perfectly! I appreciate that the second is better if I was trying to redefine the style, but actually I had 10 plt.Axes() objects and I only wanted to override the spine colour for one of them, while keeping the style pure "seaborn-dark" for the rest of them.